# Is possible, make the framework HUGO to building dynamic websites from a json?

Tags: hugo, middleman

I tested build a website with Middleman and was possible build dynamic pages with info from a json, including the url path with slug originally from Jason, but the middleman get so much time do build website if we compare it with Hugo.

So is possible, make some similar with Hugo?

Comment: I would consider staying with middleman, if your only concern is speed. I am just moving from hugo to middleman, because I keep running into limitations with go templating, and also the fact that it's not possible to create pages dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible, at least not with hugo alone.

You can read JSON from any URL and use it's data in a page (https://gohugo.io/templates/data-templates/#call-the-functions-with-a-url)

But to dynamically create new pages from JSON data is not possible in hugo, as is discussed here:

https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/140 (I used to have better links, but can't find them right now)

You can do it, by running some other script that generates the pages. As an example see

https://github.com/kidsil/hugo-data-to-pages

Answer (score -1):

It is possible but u need to make the build every time when there is an update on JSON. Hugo has the functionality to read data from the JSON file. So create the JSON file and put the file on Data folder then make the build